# Is there a way to copy a table structure to all tables in MySQL database at once?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin allows you to create a new table from a current table by copying its strucutre/strucute+data/data only...etc through a window similar to this...

[image]

However is it possible to copy the structure of a table to multiple tables in your database at once ?

Comment: Look at the code phpmyadmin uses. Replicate that

Answer (score 0):

one option would be to export the structure of the table. Then copy the sql generated by phpadmin. You could create a php script that iterates over the table names and runs the same alter/create query but replaces the table name.

You can do this using the `show TABLES;` query in mysql to get the tables then run `alter $row[0] ...` or `create $row[0] ...` queries from the export to do the work for you. just replace the table name with the varable name you have set in your loop.